# Fifties sci-fi - "No concept of" a ghoul

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to recall a science fiction short (?) story, probably from the 1950s, which included a passage with the following lines:

> Graves in a cemetery dug up. Corpses eaten [Horrible] but it's merely a ghoul. [But] if there were no idea of a ghoul, and no concept of one. Then dug-up half-eaten corpses are found. Nameless horror.

Does this ring any bells?

I've got a hazy thought that it might be Henry Kuttner, but can't swear to it.

Comment: Pretty accurately remembered wording!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[The Angelic Angleworm](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62771) by Fredric Brown.

It's a novella rather than a short story. The paragraph is:

> Even something as familiar as a commonplace ghoul. Graves in a cemetery dug up, corpses eaten. Horrible thing, it may be; but it’s merely a ghoul; as long as it’s named—But suppose, if you can stand it, there was no such word as ghoul and no concept of one. Then dug-up half-eaten corpses are found. Nameless horror.

You can find it a few lines into chapter 4.

Comment: For anyone else whose curiosity was piqued by this snippet, the full text is available to read at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Unknown_v06n05_1943-02_slpn/page/n48/mode/1up).